# How can i calculated the number of connected relationship in NEO4j?

Tags: neo4j, nodes, relationship

I have data that connects `IP` address to `IC` and `ID`. 
How can I count the first and second degree relationship?

First degree relationship means how many relationship are connected to the first node. So from `113.210.1.15` to `81121610`, there is 8 relationships.
As for second degree relationship, `81121610` is connected to 2 nodes (`WXM8810` and `WWE8110`) `WXM8810` have 3 relationships with 3 other nodes, while `WWE8110` has 2 relationships with 2 other nodes. So second degree relationship would be the average of both the 3 and 2 relationship, which is 2.5

Here is a picture of my data:
[image]

Comment: The `IP` in your node is truncated. Can you provide a more readable pic ?

Comment: Your image shows 4 node colors, which probably means there are 4 labels; what label is each color for? Also, are you mainly interested in finding: (1) the number of blue nodes connected to a specific red node, and (2) the average number of gray nodes connected to the yellow nodes that are connected to that red node?

Answer (score 0):

Since your question does not provide enough information, I will make some assumptions. Also, since your image shows 4 node colors but your question only lists 3 node labels, I will just use the node colors as their labels.

I assume that you are interested in finding these 2 things:

1. The number of Blue nodes connected to a specific Red node.
2. The average number of Gray nodes connected to the Yellow nodes that are connected to that Red node

   ```
   MATCH (blue:Blue)-[:CONNECTED]->(red:Red {id: '81121610'})
   WITH red, COUNT(blue) AS blue_count
   MATCH (red)-[:CONNECTED]->(yellow:Yellow)-[:CONNECTED]->(gray:Gray)
   WITH red, blue_count, yellow, COUNT(gray) AS gray_count
   RETURN red, blue_count, AVG(gray_count) AS avg_gray_count
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I would like to get 2 things:

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I would like to get 2 things:
1. when blue is connected to red. How many other blue are also connected to red.
2. when the same red node is connected to a yellow node, how many other red nodes are also connected to it?
3. when the same yellow node is connected to a grey node, how many other yellow nodes are also connected to it?

So in return it will produce a table by saying each blue node, what is the average count of relationship tie to it.

Comment: Can you give an example of the "table" that you expect to get for the data in your image?